# Is it possible to detect if base_auth succeeds in nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx

I want to protect the admin area of my site using base_auth, the configuration looks like

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
     auth_basic 'Restricted';
     auth_basic_user_file /opt/webroot/.htpasswd;

     # this section is supposed to be valid only if auth_basic succeeds 
     if (!-e $request_filename ){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
        break;
     }
}
```

since the 'admin' does not exist actually, it's a virtual path. the rewrite rules always applies whether the authentication succeeds or not.

My question is, it it possible to apply the rewrite rules only if the auth_basic is  successfully authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `try_files`.

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
     auth_basic 'Restricted';
     auth_basic_user_file /opt/webroot/.htpasswd;

     try_files $uri /index.php;
}
```

Comment: awesome, it works. 
I thought try_files should hehave same as rewrite.

Comment: Not exactly. And they are executed at different [phases](http://wiki.nginx.org/Phases).